# How to sum second element in string?

Tags: python

I try to sum per fruit sort the total.

So I have it:

```
listfruit= [('Watermeloenen', '123,20'), ('Watermeloenen', '2.772,00'), ('Watermeloenen', '46,20'), ('Watermeloenen', '577,50'), ('Watermeloenen', '69,30'), ('Appels', '3.488,16'), ('Sinaasappels', '137,50'), ('Sinaasappels', '500,00'), ('Sinaasappels', '1.000,00'), ('Sinaasappels', '2.000,00'), ('Sinaasappels', '1.000,00'), ('Sinaasappels', '381,25')]

def total_cost_fruit_per_sort():
    number_found = listfruit   

    fruit_dict = {}
    for n, f in number_found:
        fruit_dict[f] = fruit_dict.get(f, 0) + int(n)
        result = '\n'.join(f'{key}: {val}' for key, val in fruit_dict.items())
    return result 

print(total_cost_fruit_per_sort())
```

So that it looks like:

```
Watermeloenen: 800
Sinaasappels: 1000
```

But if I run the code I get this error:

```
 File "c:\Users\engel\Documents\python\code\extract_text.py", line 292, in <genexpr>
    result = sum(int(n) for _, n in listfruit)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '123,20'
```

But I parse the second value to an int, even when I try to do it to parse to float. Doesn't work.

Question: how can I can calculate total of each fruit sort?

Comment: use `.` to separate decimals, e.g. `123.2`, not `123,2`

Comment: @Rafaó. But this are the numbers I get from a tex file. So I first have to convert them? I can not change them manually

Comment: I can not see line from error message in your code. What line is the actual one? May you edit your question please? Btw `int` function can not parse '.' and ',' symbols. Also if you want decimals, you must use `float` and remove thousands separator

Comment: yeah, convert them using `replace`. Firstly get rid of points (`.replace('.', '')`), then convert commas to dots (`replace(',', '.')`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution exploiting `.replace` to handle `.` and `,` in the strings and `eval` to transform them to numeric.

```
def total_cost_fruit_per_sort(debug=False):
    number_found = listfruit   

    fruit_dict = {}
    for f, n in number_found:
        parsed_n = eval(n.replace('.', '').replace(',', '.'))
        if debug:
            print(f, n, parsed_n)
        fruit_dict[f] = fruit_dict.get(f, 0) + parsed_n
        result = '\n'.join(f'{key}: {val}' for key, val in fruit_dict.items())
    return result 

print(total_cost_fruit_per_sort())
```

This gives as output:

```
Watermeloenen: 3588.2
Appels: 3488.16
Sinaasappels: 5018.75
```

In case you want to double check the string-to-numeric conversions you can run the function with the argument `debug=True` enabled.

Answer (score 3):

Since your numbers are localized with specific separators for thousands and decimals, the proper way to do this is to use the locales module to parse the numbers. (They could be "brute-force" parsed by hard-coding replacements of "." for "" and "," for "." - and for beginner programmers sometime it is more important to understand the mechanics of doing this than copying and pasting the appropriate locale functionality usage - a seasoned programmer has to understand both ways, and "feel in the guts" that going through locale is better in this case).

From your fruit names, I assume you are at NL locale, which uses "," for decimal separator in numbers. After setting the locale, a call to `locale.delocalize` will convert the number representation to use nothing as a thousands separator, and "." as the decimal separator, at which point one can call Python's "float" (not "int") to convert it to a number.

```
import locale

...

def total_cost_fruit_per_sort():

    locale.set_locale(locale.LC_NUMERIC, ("nl", "utf-8"))   

    fruit_dict = {}
    for f, n in list_fruit:
        fruit_dict[f] = fruit_dict.get(f, 0) + float(locale.delocalize(n))
    return fruit_dict  # no reason to manually convert the dict to a string: printing a dict already has the format you are trying to achieve
```

(Unfortunately locale naming is non-uniform across operating systems - you might need to try variants on the ('nl', 'utf-8')  part of the set_locale call if that fails. If you are on Windows and it fails, try first replacing 'utf-8' by 'iso8859-1').

And the brute-force method, were one does not care that the program will ever work with other numeric formats, nor are worried with possible edge cases in the format:

```
def total_cost_fruit_per_sort():
  
    fruit_dict = {}
    for f, n in list_fruit:
        n = n.replace(".", "").replace(",", ".")
        fruit_dict[f] = fruit_dict.get(f, 0) + float(n)
    return fruit_dict
```

Comment: Ah, yes, very nice: {'Watermeloenen': 3588.2, 'Appels': 3488.16, 'Sinaasappels': 5018.75}

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
import locale

locale._override_localeconv = {'thousands_sep': '.', 'decimal_point': ','}
new_listfruit = [(n, locale.atof(v)) for n, v in listfruit]
```

Output:

```
>>> new_listfruit
[('Watermeloenen', 123.2), ('Watermeloenen', 2772.0), ('Watermeloenen', 46.2), ('Watermeloenen', 577.5), ('Watermeloenen', 69.3), ('Appels', 3488.16), ('Sinaasappels', 137.5), ('Sinaasappels', 500.0), ('Sinaasappels', 1000.0), ('Sinaasappels', 2000.0), ('Sinaasappels', 1000.0), ('Sinaasappels', 381.25)]
```

Now you can do any operations with floats (and remember that you might need to reset the locale to the default setting).

Comment: meh. nice pragmatic approach to overcoming non-uniform locale namings across systems.  I spent more minutes than I wished trying to get the "nl" locale to work on Ubuntu under WSL in an en-US windows box. The world sure needs an improvement there.

Comment: @jsbueno I did the same, but didn't find a nice solution :) My solution is definitely not ideal, it's even using what should be a private dict. So yeah, the world sure needs an improvement here haha

Answer (score 1):

I believe you want to achieve something like this:

```py
result = sum(float(n.replace(".", "").replace(",", ".")) for _, n in listfruit)
```

UPD:

```
listfruit = [('Watermeloenen', '123,20'), ('Watermeloenen', '2.772,00'), ('Watermeloenen', '46,20'), ('Watermeloenen', '577,50'), ('Watermeloenen', '69,30'), ('Appels', '3.488,16'), ('Sinaasappels', '137,50'), ('Sinaasappels', '500,00'), ('Sinaasappels', '1.000,00'), ('Sinaasappels', '2.000,00'), ('Sinaasappels', '1.000,00'), ('Sinaasappels', '381,25')]


def total_cost_fruit_per_sort():
    fruit_dict = {}
    for fruit, num in listfruit:
        fruit_dict[fruit] = fruit_dict.get(fruit, 0) + float(num.replace(".", "").replace(",", "."))
    return fruit_dict


for fruit, total in total_cost_fruit_per_sort().items():
    print(f"{fruit}: {total}")
```

Comment: ah sure, I forgot the closing bracket. let me fix it